# How to mirror a specific branch between two Azure DevOps/VSTS repositories

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a Azure DevOps/VSTS project with two Git repositories, `repoMain` and `repoMirror`. The repository `repoMain` has a Master branch and a separate branch `newBranch`. The repository `repoMirror` is still empty.

How can I set up a build pipeline (with a Command Line task? Powershell task?) such that whenever something is checked in into `newBranch`, the changes are pushed into the other repository `repoMirror`? In other words, `repoMirror` should always (and only) contain the current contents of `newBranch`.

Comment: Why do you need to have two identical repos in the same team project?

Comment: @DanielMann It doesn't have to be in the same project, but the goal is to restrict some users to be able to only read repoMirror. It is not possible to set separate read permissions on different branches of the same repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I also tried this for one of my projects. Let me give you all the steps that I followed.

1. Firstly create a **newBranch** branch in the **repoMirror**
2. Now create a CI build pipeline using a windows agent
3. Add a PowerShell script task with the following commands

`git clone https://pat@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repoMain`

`cd repoMain`

`git checkout newBranch`

`git remote add Reponame https://pat@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repoMirror`

`git push Reponame newBranch -f`

[image]

4. Finally create a trigger for **repoMain** --->**newBranch** So when ever there is  any code update in **repoMain** --->**newBranch** the pipe will be executed

   [image]